# How to copy specific file from sub-folder to another Folder in R?

Tags: r

Happy New Year!

Hi,

I want to copy a file with a specific name in subfolders to another folder (with the same name of the main folder).
To clarify my question I make an example. Parent folder (“Histomach “) contains 60 subfolders (i.e.first_subfolder: “TCGA_02”, ”TCGA_06”,…  ) and each folder contains 4 subfolders (i.e.second_subfolder: “f”, ”T1”, ”T2”, ”t1c”)  also in each of them there are multiple files.

I want to choose the specific file from these file with the pattern like "_skullstrip_out.nii" and copy it to another Folder(i.e. “base-line”), with the same first subfolders names (i.e. “TCGA-02”, ”TCGA_06”,…).

I tried this code.

```html
parent_folder<-"D:/PHD/HISTOMATCH"
setwd(parent_folder)
mainfolder<-list.files(parent_folder)
first_subfolder<-list.dirs(parent_folder,recursive = FALSE)
newdir<-"D:/PHD/base_line"
dir.create(newdir)
for(i in 1:length(mainfolder)){
  
  folder<-dir.create(paste(newdir,mainfolder[i]))}

  for(i in 1:length(mainfolder)){
    second_subfolder<-list.dirs(first_subfolder[i],
                                 recursive = FALSE)
    for(f in 1:length(second_subfolder)){
      filesname<-list.files(second_subfolder[f])
      selectefile<-grepl('-skullStrip_Output.nii.gz$',filesname)
      file.copy(from =second_subfolder[f] ,to=paste(newdir,mainfolder[i]))
      
    }
}
```

The copy failed, although no error has occurred.

How can I deal with this problem?

I would be really appreciated if you could give me the solution of this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, I think the following will get you far. At least, all your `for` loops should not be necessary. Instead, you should use the existing file manipulation functions with the recursive argument.

You did not provide any data to use. I played around with the the files in the R directory. I tried to do essentially the same thing with all .pdf-files inside the "doc"-folder and copy them to a "mytest" folder at the same level as "doc" (i.e. the working dir).

```
# To make a reproducible example  
setwd(R.home()) # Your working dir should be the folder "PHD" that contains "Histomach". 

# Define from and to dirs, and the file pattern
from_dir <- "doc"     # should be "Histomach" in your case
to_dir   <- "mytest"  # "base-line"
pattern  <- ".pdf"    # "_skullstrip_out.nii",


# Get all relevant files
the_files <- list.files(path = from_dir, 
                        recursive = TRUE,
                        pattern = pattern)

# Create the "to_dir" as well as all corresponding subdirs (where files to copy were found)
sapply(file.path(to_dir, dirname(the_files)), 
       dir.create, recursive = TRUE, showWarnings = FALSE)

# Copy the files
file.copy(from = file.path(from_dir, the_files), 
          to   = file.path(to_dir,   the_files))
```

Does that do what you want?

To clean up the mess I made in your R folder, run

```
file.remove(file.path(to_dir, the_files))
```