# R copy one file to all subdirectories

Tags: r, file-copying

I'm working on an R script where I create multiple sub-folders according to some parameters. After everything I have to do I then have to copy one file into all of these new sub-folders.

Is there a way in R to do this easily? I would like to avoid `for` loops if I can. I've read about `file.copy` but that doesn't seem to do the trick (from what I've read, it works the opposite way: it copies everything from a folder -including subfolders and their contents if `recursive=TRUE`- to a new folder, whereas I want one specific file copied to all subdirectories of a folder)

I've seen questions like [Copy files from folders and sub-folders to another folder and saving the structure of the folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56377885/copy-files-from-folders-and-sub-folders-to-another-folder-and-saving-the-structu), [How to copy specific file from sub-folder to another Folder in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54051943/how-to-copy-specific-file-from-sub-folder-to-another-folder-in-r) or [Copy folder recursive in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453455/copy-folder-recursive-in-r) but that's just the opposite direction of what I want.

Comment: Assuming you want to copy 1 file to several created subfolders, you will have to call `file.copy()` for each subfolder. You can use either a for loop or a call to one of the functions that hides the loop, like `sapply`. Why are you trying to avoid the loop?

Comment: Oh really? I must admit, I haven't tried it myself. Even better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file.copy()` has vectorized `from` and `to` arguments.  If you have a vector of directories you want to copy the file to you can simply do:

```
filename <- "my_file.txt"

to_directories <- c("dir 1", "dir 2", "dir 3")

file.copy(filename, file.path(to_directories, filename))

[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: So I would need to first get a list of all subdirectories, right?

Comment: Yes, you will need a vector of the subdirectories you want to copy to.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying something like that but was somehow messing up the new_folders/file.txt paths.

Comment: I'm sorry, but a follo-up question has come up. Is there a way to quiet `file.copy` so it doesn't show `TRUE TRUE TRUE` messages?

Comment: Wrap it in `invisible()`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the `invisible()` function. So simple!